# Reducing the integration dimensions using function property in numerics

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Let's say I want to compute the 2D integral

$$ I = \int\int dx dy~f(x,y) $$

for some function f over all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now, let's assume that $f$ can be rewritten as

$$ f(x, y) = g(x-y) =: g(z) $$

How can I express $I$ by an integral over $g(z)$? Of course, I am not looking for $ I = \int\int dx dy~g(x-y) $. Ultimately, this should be used for a numerical task, where only the $z=x-y$ axis is known and can of course only be integrated once.